# Explanation of the grammar in 逮捕しといてくれ。

Tags: contractions, subsidiary-verbs

> 逮捕しといてくれ。

I know the sentence is a command/plea, and that's why くれ, but I don't understand the しといて. Why is that or what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

しといて is a contraction of しておいて (cf. ておく : do something as preparation for some purpose). Arrest him so he doesn't cause any more trouble.